# Socket.IO with Django, Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-socketio

I'm trying to set up a Django server with Socket.io running. I've looked all over the place and tried a million different things but I can't figure out how to get nginx and gunicorn to play nice with django-socketio. Can anyone help? Specifically, is there a tutorial anyone can point me to that they have successfully gotten to work? Thanks!

Comment: Better idea: Use django channels: http://channels.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I'm not sure that will do what I want. I don't see any way to send messages back from the client? Is there a javascript library that accompanies this?

Comment: @NickThompson django-channels is in alpha at best, it's not ready for production, It should be merged into Django in 1.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to have a nginx block that catches socket.io frames and forwards them to your the django-socketio server. Assuming thats running on port 9000, try:

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
       }
```

A good tutorial can also be found [here](https://twixtiles.com/blog/)
.

Comment: Tried this out, and FINALLY!! Thanks so much!